# What can I use to read MapInfo files in Java?

Tags: mapinfo, java, tab, mif

I want to read MapInfo files using Java.
 Before I used geotools for this but now I have problems with the GDAL library in Win7x64. Can i find geotools or gdal only for Java? To it not usede gdal's dlls only Java classes. 
 I found the [MITAB](http://mitab.maptools.org/) library but its only for C++.
Does anyone know something that can help me?

**UPADTE**

Another question: i read geotools quickstart and dont se any words about Gdal. But when i try use geotools i get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gdal/ogr/ogr
at org.geotools.data.ogr.OGRDataStore.<clinit>(OGRDataStore.java:169)
```

When i add `gdal.jre` in build path all works fine.
Whats wrong?

Comment: It might be best to ask your question in another thread to conform with the SE format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the **experimental** [OGR plugin](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/ogr.html) to do this in GeoTools.

Try adding

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-ogr</artifactId>
  <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml - I've not tried but I expect it will pull down all the stuff you need.

Comment: Its posible to use only Eclipse without maven?

Comment: It's really not recommended, maven makes life easy for you!

Comment: can you say i get gdal for Win 64bit from there http://vbkto.dyndns.org:1280/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-1-9-mapserver-6-2.zip . Its correct?

Comment: only if you have a 64bit Java install.